# Laravel password check for changing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 I have the following condition to see if the user has inserted his current password correctly, and if yes, then do something.

Here is the code:

```
if(Auth::user()->password==Hash::make(Input::get('old_password')) )
           {
               echo 'done';
           }
```

But it does not meet the condition. Why?

Answer (score 22):

Because part of the hash is the salt which will never be the same. You need to use the `Hash::check` method instead which knows what to do properly. So...

```
if (Hash::check(Input::get('old_password'), Auth::user()->password)) { 
    echo 'done';
}
```

Comment: you should switch the place of parameters you've just passed to the `hash::check()`

Comment: cheers, I had someone check it because I was being lazy and wasn't going to check order but they clearly trolled me so I would be wrong. fuuu @andreas

Comment: it should be `if (Hash::check(Input::get('old_password'), Auth::user()->password))`

Comment: yeah my bad, when I first edited this I wasn't paying much attention obviously

Answer (score 2):

Auth::validate is also an option if your end goal is to make sure the user is who he/she says they are.

```
$credentials = ['email' => Auth::user()->email, 'password' => Input::get('old_password')];

if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {
    echo "Successful";
}
```

Comment: 'password' passed to Auth::validate should be the plaintext password, not the hashed password.

Comment: Can you share why? If I am doing something wrong when ensuring a user has entered the right password, I'd like to know!.

Comment: You are doing 2 things wrong. First you are passing the password from the database so it will always be "right" but then it is a hash going into the check which wants the plain text. Your password here should be input, not the user models password.

Comment: My apologies, I jumped the gun. I checked my files and I missed the fact that I always use it in correspondence with Input::get. I'm deleting it, just wanted someone to clarify for me.

Comment: Actually, I just corrected it. I noticed he is using Input::get. My mistake.